# next build `pages/404` can not have getInitialProps/getServerSideProps but I do not have getInitialProps or getServerSideProps

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I've tried searching around but can't find anyone with my issue.
When I run `next build` I get an error saying I cannot have getInitalProps/getServerSideProps but nowhere inside of my 404.tsx file do I use getInitalProps or getServerSideProps.

```
Error Message:
    Error: `pages/404` can not have getInitialProps/getServerSideProps, https://err.sh/next.js/404-get-initial-props
    at /Users/myuser/.nvm/versions/node/v15.5.0/lib/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js:15:5606
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:93:5)
    at async /Users/myuser/.nvm/versions/node/v15.5.0/lib/node_modules/next/dist/build/tracer.js:3:470
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async /Users/myuser/.nvm/versions/node/v15.5.0/lib/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js:15:2910
    at async /Users/myuser/.nvm/versions/node/v15.5.0/lib/node_modules/next/dist/build/tracer.js:3:470
    at async /Users/myuser/.nvm/versions/node/v15.5.0/lib/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js:15:2147
    at async /Users/myuser/.nvm/versions/node/v15.5.0/lib/node_modules/next/dist/build/tracer.js:3:470
```

But my 404 file looks like this:

```
import * as React from 'react';

import Head from 'next/head';
import Layout from '../components/Layout';

const Error = () => {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <Head>
        <title>TM</title>
      </Head>
      <h1>Error 404</h1>
      <h2>Page not found</h2>
    </Layout>
  );
};

export default Error;
```

Layout component: I commented out default props thinking maybe it was causing it for some weird reason.

```
import * as React from 'react';

import Footer from './Footer';
import Head from 'next/head';
import Header from './Header';
import styles from '../styles/main.module.css';

type Props = {
  showFooter?: boolean;
  showHeader?: boolean;
  title?: string;
};

const Layout: React.FC<Props> = ({
  showFooter,
  showHeader,
  title,
  children,
}) => {
  showFooter = showFooter || true;
  showHeader = showHeader || true;
  title = title || 'title';
  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <title>{title}</title>
      </Head>
      {showHeader && <Header />}
      <div className={styles.content}>{children}</div>
      {showFooter && <Footer />}
    </div>
  );
};

// Layout.defaultProps = {
//   showFooter: true,
//   showHeader: true,
//   title: 'title',
// };

export default Layout;
```

Comment: I ended up fixing my issues. The version of node I was using was different than the one specified in my package.json. 
1. nvm use *node version specified under engine in my package.json*
2. npm install (This will reinstall the packages compatible with that node version)
3. rerun next build... 

If you still have issues with it then try to clear your npm cache, delete node_modules and if you really have too delete your package-lock... 
Hope that helps anyone else who has this issue in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up fixing my issues. The version of node I was using was different than the one specified in my package.json.

1. nvm use node version specified under engine in my package.json
2. npm install (This will reinstall the packages compatible with that node version)
3. rerun next build... If you still have issues with it then try to clear your npm cache, delete node_modules and if you really have too delete your package-lock and then go back to step 2 again.
   Hope that helps anyone else who has this issue in the future.